# Selecting using the Path tool in Photoshop merges parts of the selection? (CS6)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, path, selections

[image: Example]

When trying to select an area using the path tool the selection merges parts of the area but not others? Tried with AA off/on.

Solutions?

(CS6)

Comment: Maybe the paths which missing in the selection are not closed?

Comment: VTC unclear, it's not possible to tell what the problem is without more information or a screenshot of the paths/layers panels

Answer (score 1):

Is very possible that some of the shape have different overlapping modes.

Select the shapes where you have problem with **Path Selection** tool and changes the overlapping modes in **Option Toolbar** to **Subtract**.
[image: a]